# Why is fuel leaking from the carburetor on my generator?

Tags: generator

i have Honda clone gx 160 Chinese generator, fuel is leaking from side which is attached to intake of head, i have cleaned carb checked the float. float is working properly. i have sucked air turning it upside down and could not suck any air hence fuel will also not pass. i have replaced intake side gasket too, this also did not worked. what could be the problem.

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to home improvement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about home improvement

Comment: Repair of major appliances is specifically on-topic. A generator falls under the same category as a furnace if it's your primary power source, in my opinion. We also support repair of lawn mowers, for example.

Comment: How do you know that the float is working properly? Sounds to me like it isn't. Is the needle clean and in good condition?

Answer (score 2):

On my generators I turn the fuel off and run the carb out of fuel for several reasons the first being a tiny pice of crud in the seat for the float valve would be impossible to detect in most cases even my Onan will leak like this some times so it’s a good idea to turn off the fuel, reason #2 when fuel is left in the carb the methanol eats up some of the seals and absorbs moisture, while doing this debris from the degraded rubber parts and fuel lines cause leaks. It is a good idea when done running your generator to remove the load and turn the fuel off letting it run until it dies this helps keep the carb clean and the only negative is you have to open the fuel valve and wait a minute for the bowl to fill up prior to starting. This also provides some additional cool down time for the alternator.